"Sign Out" button and logo not clickable
I have a menu bar which I created with HTML and CSS.
I have buttons that are centralized in the middle of the menu bar, which work perfectly fine. My problem here is that the buttons on the wings, "Sign Out" button and logo button, are not clickable. These 2 buttons are aligned well and in proper placement, just I cannot click them for some reason.


<div style="background-color: #f8f9fa; padding: 0px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; height: 70px; position: relative;justify-content: space-between;">
    <div>
      <a href="https://www.test.com/" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="static/LOGO 1.png" alt="Logo" style="max-height: 60px; margin-left: 15px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="hamburger" style="display: none; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 15px;">
      <div style="width: 25px; height: 3px; background-color: black; margin: 5px 0;"></div>
      <div style="width: 25px; height: 3px; background-color: black; margin: 5px 0;"></div>
      <div style="width: 25px; height: 3px; background-color: black; margin: 5px 0;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="menu-items" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
      <div style="margin: 0 20px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <a href="https://www.test.com/myclips" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; margin-right: 5px;">My Clips</a>
        <span style="background-color: #007bff; color: #ffffff; padding: 3px 8px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700;">
            {{ myclips }}
          </span>
      </div>
      
      <div style="margin: 0 20px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <a href="https://www.test.com/myhighlights" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; margin-right: 5px;">My Highlights</a>
        <span style="background-color: #007bff; color: #ffffff; padding: 3px 8px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700;">
            {{ myhighlights }}
        </span>
      </div>
      
      <div style="margin: 0 20px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <a href="https://www.test.com/mymatches" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; margin-right: 5px;">My Matches</a>
        <span style="background-color: #007bff; color: #ffffff; padding: 3px 8px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700;">
            {{ mymatches }}
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div style="margin: 0px; display: flex; align-items: right;">
      <a href="https://www.test.com/logout" style="background-color: #00bbff; color: #ffffff; border: none; padding: 6px 12px; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; margin-right: 15px; font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none;">Sign Out</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="mobile-menu" style="display: none; background-color: #f8f9fa; position: absolute; top: 100px; width: 100%; box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); z-index: 1000;">
    <a href="https://www.test.com/myclips" style="padding-left: 50px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; margin: 10px 0;">
      My Clips
      <span style="margin-right: 50px; background-color: #007bff; color: #ffffff; padding: 3px 8px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700;">
        {{ myclips }}
      </span>
    </a>
    
    <a href="https://www.test.com/myhighlights" style="padding-left: 50px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; margin: 10px 0;">
      My Highlights
      <span style="margin-right: 50px; background-color: #007bff; color: #ffffff; padding: 3px 8px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700;">
          {{ myhighlights }}
      </span>
    </a>
  
    <a href="https://www.test.com/mymatches" style="padding-left: 50px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; margin: 10px 0;">
      My Matches
      <span style="margin-right: 50px; background-color: #007bff; color: #ffffff; padding: 3px 8px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700;">
        {{ mymatches }}
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>



My goal is to have the button "Sign Out" and the logo image both clickable.

It's appears you've a broken html. Check the second div tag, and try to close properly

@flpms I forgot to copy the last line. Fixed

@David I tried, but now the middle menu items are aligned to the right, and the buttons still not clickable.

Protip: inline styles are a nightmare for all involved. It's very difficult to analyze your layout with it like that, and making changes involves a ton of repetitious work. Please use CSS with intuitively named classes for reusability.

The most recent update to the code in the question no longer appears to demonstrate the problem...

@David But on bigger screens, bigger than this snippet, it doesn't work for some reason

@David It works on small screens.

@U13-Forward: "It doesn't work" isn't a clear or specific description of a problem.  The UI does what I expect it to do when I test it, regardless of screen size.  What specific screen size are you testing and what specific problem are you observing?  If you're observing that problem in the code snippet above and I am not then it may be browser-specific, have you tested in multiple browsers?

@David My computer size is 12.8" x 7.2", and what I'm observing is that the buttons on the wings are not clickable. I'm using chrome, I tested edge and it doesn't work there either. And dimensions 1920x1080.

@U13-Forward: Testing the code snippet above in that resolution does not demonstrate the described issue for me.  The original code in the question did, but since then the updates made to the question appear to have quietly corrected the issue when I test it.

The <div id="menu-items"> is styled to be the full width of its container, so it has empty space that's obscuring those other elements beneath it.
Remove its absolute positioning and its 100% width, also remove the auto margin from the first part of the header, and use space-between on their shared parent element to distribute them.  For example:


<div style="background-color: #f8f9fa; padding: 0px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; height: 70px; position: relative;justify-content: space-between;">
      <div>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/test" style="text-decoration: none;">
              <img src="static/LOGO 1.png" alt="Logo" style="max-height: 60px; margin-left: 15px;">
          </a>
      </div>
    <div id="menu-items" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
      <div style="margin: 0 20px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/test" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; margin-right: 5px;">Test</a>
            <span style="background-color: #007bff; color: #ffffff; padding: 3px 8px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700;">
              100
            </span>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 0 20px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/test" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; margin-right: 5px;">Test</a>
            <span style="background-color: #007bff; color: #ffffff; padding: 3px 8px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700;">
              100
          </span>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 0 20px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/test" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; margin-right: 5px;">Test</a>
            <span style="background-color: #007bff; color: #ffffff; padding: 3px 8px; border-radius: 4px; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; font-weight: 700;">
              100
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 0px; display: flex; align-items: right;">
        <a href="https://www.example.com/logout" style="background-color: #00bbff; color: #ffffff; border: none; padding: 6px 12px; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer; font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif; margin-right: 15px; font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none;">Sign Out</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Overall, there's a lot that CSS flexbox can do to style your elements.  It's better to make use of that than to try and manually position things with combinations of absolute positioning, margins, false widths, etc.

Thanks for your answer! It doesn't work though, I edited my full code into the question, could you please take a look, thanks!

@U13-Forward: What "doesn't work" about it?  When I test the code snippet in this answer, all 5 links are clickable and the center items remain centered.

I realized that it works on smaller screens

But on bigger screens, bigger than this snippet, it doesn't work for some reason

My computer size is 12.8" x 7.2", and what I'm observing is that the buttons on the wings are not clickable. I'm using chrome, I tested edge and it doesn't work there either. And dimensions 1920x1080.

@U13-Forward: Testing the code snippet above in that resolution does not reproduce the issue for me.  Note that the answer posted is based on the original question, not based on the updated question which also does not demonstrate the issue.

I tried again, same issue, now the middle buttons in the menu bar aren't aligned properly as well.

@U13-Forward: Then something else is wrong with your browser.  When I test the code snippet in the answer above in Chrome, all 5 links are clickable and successfully navigate to example.com.

I figured my problem, it is another div that I had no idea was there. I'm gonna accept and upvote since you helped me organize my code properly.

This happens a lot of times when your other elements are covering your button. Your third image is completely covering your button. You could make it into a collapsible menu and then display all the items in a list, or wrap the button to a second row.

If u use javascript add an id for it , and u can use onclick event in java , or add an onclick event inside html tag.
To be “clickeable” set cursor to pointer in css for those items

Please see [ask]. Solutions should be specific, showing code when possible. Also, don't write in txtspk. Write like a professional, in real English. Take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

add link to the official documentation please
